# VBA: How to pass Cell.Address() into a usable sheet.range.select format so I can put a new value into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello this is a vba question. I have a user defined range (Response1) of cells, which I am then referring to using a *For each Cell in Response1 range* loop construct.
What I struggle with is while I cycle through the *For each Cell in Response1* I want to iteratively change the value adjacent to the Current Cell that is active in the loop.
I have gotten so far as using Cell.Address() to determine the address of the current active cell (e.g. $B$3$), but I can't figure out how to then use this Cell.Address() to actually specify the sheet.range (cell address). offset(0,1). value = desired value.
Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance everyone!
Stay safe and best wishes.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
For Each Cell In Response1
For cnter = 1 To FinalRow
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(cnter, 3)) = Cell.Value Then
    add = Cell.Address()
    'Now put a myvalue in the cell adjacent to the current Cell being looked at:
    'NEED HELP: Sheets("Quadrants").Range("add" variable here).Offset(0,1).value = myvalue
    End If
Next cnter
Next Cell
```

Comment: Don't use the address. Just use `Cell.Offset(,1)`.

Comment: If I misunderstand your question, and you want to use the address of the `Cell`, but refer to a different sheet, then just `Sheets("Quadrants").Range(add).Offset(0,1)` - no quotes.

Comment: Hi BigBen - thank you so much for your help! I feel like such a noob, that was a lot easier than I thought. I didn't even think of just trying it because I thought it must be more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: @BigBen Thank you so much!